# Whats is Vista 4GL?

Tags: 4gl

Not going to hide the fact I am a recruitment consultant.

However I have a requirement come in for a Vista 4GL Developer.

I have tried googling Visa 4GL however not much is coming up.

Is Vista 4GL similar to Progress 4GL?

If anyone wants to point me in the right direction that would be ace.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked as a developer for VISTA and one or two of their clients – back in 90s! So, this is based on what I knew then. As another contributor said, it’s a development language aligned very much to the publishing industry (a package for books, another for journals) – but there was also a ‘financials’ package. At that time, there were non-publisher clients who only took the financial package.

Progress (I think) is an RDBMS only – so, not the same thing.

Comment: Progress has a 4GL language as well, now called Progress ABL. Dont know of any relation to Vista.

Answer (score 2):

My company tried it for a project in the mid 80s.

Up to then we had only developed in cobol.

After much pain and wasted time we realised (at that time anyway)
that Vista had been used to write a system for oxfod university press
and in fact, thats was all you could write with it.

(we later dabbled in Mimer - possibly the only ones who ever did)

Austin

Answer (score 1):

Vista 4GL is a very niche language - it's used almost exclusively amongst publishers (In fact if memory serves the whole thing is keyed by ISBN). I can't comment on the similarity to progress I'm afraid, although I developed for several years in Vista 4GL I've no experience with Progress.

I last developed with Vista 4GL in 1999 and even back then it was a very small community of developers; so small that I'd be confident to hazard a guess that your client is based in the UK in essex...

Good luck with the search!